# Twitter API user info on a certain date

Tags: datetime, twitter

I recently learned that I can access twitter user info with the following API parameters:
ex. http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=barackobama

How to get the user information of ex. barack obama on ex. 12 september 2012 ?

subquestion: is there any way to get this information directly into excel? I got a spreadsheet with 20 usernames, and I would like to have their amount of followers listed in the cell next to their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Twitter will only return the last ~3,200 tweets.  If that's outside your time range, you're out of luck.

Comment: Most of these users have around the 1000 - 1500 tweets. Is it possible in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the tweets of a user that are posted between today and last week. You can take a look at the search api limitations to understand the limits. You can search with a date query but you can only search up to one week ago.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search